# NotifyDataChanged from service Android

Tags: android, service, android-listview

I have service that updates a database on my android APP. The thing is that the views  on the APP itself (listviews) won't get notified if I don't explicitly call the  "myAdapter.notifyDataChanged()" method. How can I do this from a service? Where I have no reference to the adapter nor the activity holding it.

I thought of firing my own custom event, but I don't know if that's even possible in android. I couldn't find anything on the API documentation.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: How are you communicating with the service? Via startSerice, or are you binding?

Comment: I'm using startService. (the main activity doen't interface with the service directly, but with a DB)   SERVICE --> DB <-- ACTIVITY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a message bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), etc.).

Or, use a `Messenger`.

Or, wrap your database in a `ContentProvider` and use a `CursorLoader` to populate the adapter, as you will be handed a new `Cursor` when you change the content in that `ContentProvider` (assuming you implement it correctly).

Comment: The first method "LocalBroadcastManager" worked as a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The elegant way is having your activity bind to the service using `bindService`. In this call you need to provide a custom ServiceConnection object which has a callback function called `onServiceConnected`, where you can get a pointer to your service.

Once you have a pointer to your Service object, you can ask your Service to inform you (providing a pointer, a callback, a handler, or any other mechanism) to update the view when the database is updated.

Through this mechanism when your activity starts, it connects to the service, and when the activity ends (onPause()) you disconnect from the service.

It's not trivial, specially if you have never done this before, but this mechanism will be very useful for any kind of service.

Comment: Thanks! I know this method might be the right one to use. but I'm trying to keep it simple for now. Besides, I've struggled with binded services in the past, so I usually try to avoid them whenever I can.